# Datatable row is cutted in half when there is only one row in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using datatables's Scroller extension.

When the table have more than 1 row, the rows are displayed fine. But if the table only contains of 1 row, the "lower part" of the row isn't displayed. The table cut the row of almost in the middle.

Im trying to make a second line inside the row, using the `div` as you can see in my example. It's like the table can figure out to include it in it's height calculation if there is more than 1 row, but not if there is only 1 row. Does anyone know what I can do about it?

Focus should be here I think: `<div>second line</div>`

> html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

  <script src="http://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/Scroller/js/dataTables.scroller.js"></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

> Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            deferRender: false, // TODO learn from doc
            dom: 'f<"table-toolbar">tS',
            language: {
                "search": '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>'
            },
            stateSave: false,
            //scrollY: $(document).height() - 266,
            scrollY: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    "className": '',
                    "orderable": false,
                    "sortable": false,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "first line<div>second line</div>"
                }
            ]
        });
} );
```

> Update 1 : Fiddle where it breaks

[Fiddle where the rows dowsn't work](http://live.datatables.net/ceqijesi/6/edit)

> Update 2 : Fiddle where it works. (2 rows instead of 1 - notthing else!)

[Fiddle where the rows works](http://live.datatables.net/ceqijesi/5/edit)

Comment: I will try. Im trying already to trim my example down while reading up on the issue.

It might cause by fnMeasure is not calculating the height with _fnCalcRowHeight as I would like. Maybe I am not aloud to put in a div in a row?

Se older but simular problem here kind a. http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/10131/scroller-breaks-rowheight/p1

I have tryed using rowHeight and autoHeight now, with no luck.

Comment: I can say that with only the Naming column I have the same problem, so I will first edit and remove the other columns

Comment: @MrLister You're fiddle needs to have the Scroller extension (it contains the javascript functions used to calculate the row height).

Documentation:
https://www.datatables.net/extensions/scroller/

Comment: Oh looks like they have a "datatable-fiddle-version" here :)
http://live.datatables.net/ceduqesi/1/edit

Comment: @MrLister I have add a fiddle that works and a fiddle that doesn't work now. It's very weird.

Comment: Looks awesome. I Can use it for now for sure. The scroller extensions uses some methods to calculate the height, maybe they don't work for one row with a div. I will try to find the doc/api

Comment: They used to have a documentation for another site, maybe a 3rd part, I can't seem to find anymore. What I remember from it, they have a couple of javascript functions to calculate the height of the table and which rows to display from where you scrolled down to, instead of have pagination.
I suspect that it's this function there might be buggy or atleast when the row contains a `div`. 
My second teory is that it's a time issue, where the second line's height isn't rendered and hence has no height to be encountered for in the calculation, but I can't say why it works for multiple rows though.

Comment: Button line, you totally fixed my biggest problem atm. and made a good answer for the OP. I will accept if you want to make an answer out of your comment. Much appriciated for you're help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display problem is caused by the surrounding div (`.dataTables_scrollBody`) that causes the data to be cut off. It comes out as 37px for a one row table and 112px for a two row one. 37px is obviously not enough, so as a workaround you can put `.dataTables_scrollBody {min-height:55px}` in the CSS. That will solve the display problem. See http://live.datatables.net/ceqijesi/12/edit

To solve the actual issue however, you should dive into the JavaScript that creates the table. Or, more precisely, the div that comes after the table. It has no class, only a style attribute that defines its height. (The table itself is positioned absolutely, so it's this next div that determines the height of `.dataTables_scrollBody`.)
To confuse matters, this div has different heights in different browsers here.

Comment: I know it is an year old solution... I am facing the same issue now. Is there any better approach than this answer?

Comment: You can try "text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;" I keeps everything on one row. I'm using that for my tableheaders actually

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done with:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis; 
white-space: nowrap;
```

See [Datatables doc](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In our application, we are expecting the column to stay on a fixed width and the text to wrap (white-space: normal !important;)

Comment: Just keep in mind, that if you use Server side tables, with the Scroller extensions, in order for it to be able to calculate the rows correct, it demands _all_ the rows to be the same height.